# How to Show Total Row Count of a Radgrid in the Header of a RadTabStrip

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I have an ASP.NET project in C#  that uses a sqlDataSource. The project consists of a Telerik Radgrid, which sits on a RadTabStrip.  I would like to know how I can possibly add the total row count of that grid into the Header Tab like seen in following image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked with the RadTabStrip much so I don't know how to set that problematically; however, I've done something similar by displaying the item count elsewhere on the page.  Perhaps this will help you achieve what you desire.

First, you'll should add a HiddenField into the page which will stored the number of items in the RadGrid.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
```

Next, in the code behind, stick the number of items int he RadGrid into the HiddenField.

```
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HiddenField1.Value = RadGrid.Items.Count.ToString();
{
```

Finally, on PageLoad, grab the value of the HiddenField and append it to the tab text.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var totalItems = $("#HiddenField1").val();
   $("#OpenTradesTab").Text("Open Trades (" + totalItems  + ")")
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Stanley thanks to you pointing me in the right direction I got it working :)

Comment: this will give the number of Items on the current Grid Page

Answer (score 0):

You can get an approximate answer by doing:

dgGrid.PageCount * dgGrid.PageSize